# Order bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I need some help. I want to sort by date two different papers of the same lead author in my bibliography. At present, the paper in 2016 appears before that in 2015.
I have the bibtex package (probably biblatex can help me but it can create some problems with cite and other things too).

Comment: You'd better say what bibliography style you are using. Are you sure you have specified any sorting at all?

Comment: Best would be to add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) resulting in your issue ...

Comment: Ok Kurt, i try :)

Comment: Maybe you style sorts by citation order (`unsrt`) or by name-title-year and not name-year-title. A solution will depend on the style you use, so it would be great if you could tell us more about it. This is best done in an MWE as Kurt already mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

This problem usually appears when the name of the authors are substituted with et al. You can solve this problem adding an auxiliary command that will not appear in the reference list.

At the beginning of your BibTeX file, add:

```
@preamble{"\newcommand{\abelsort}[1]{}"}
```

Ad then, in the definition of your entries, do:

```
@article{AbelCharlesEngland,
    author = {\abelsort{1}Abel, name1, name2 charles, name3 England},
    year = {2015}
}

@article{AbelCharlesDavid,
    author = {\abelsort{2}Abel, name1, name2 charles, name3 David},
    year = {2016}
}
```

The `\abelsort` will force the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, with biblatex it's very simple as you just have to use option `sorting=nyt` (case for "name, year, title").

> biblatex can help me but it *can* create some problems with cite *and other things too*

What problems *can* you have ? In most cases, option `natbib` allows citing everything fine with `\cite`-like commands. I usually use these lines when I use biblatex :

```
\usepackage{csquotes,xpatch} % recommended for biblatex
\usepackage[natbib,backend=biber,style=ieee,citestyle=numeric,sorting=nyt,]{biblatex}
    % natbib is for using \citet, \citep, \citeauthor, etc.
    % natbib cheatsheet : http://merkel.texture.rocks/Latex/natbib.php
```